# "rails generate scaffold" error on "_from.erb" (jbuilder issue?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, jbuilder, scaffold

I'm relatively new to Ruby and Rails, been teaching myself in free time. I recently added a few gems to my gemfile, and now my scaffold is giving me errors--couldn't find another answer on StackOverflow that addressed my issue (apologies in advance if my search prowess isn't up to par).

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

# Set up local .env file, require immediately
gem 'dotenv-rails', :require => 'dotenv/rails-now'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'duktape'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  # Mailcatcher for local mail debugging
  gem 'mailcatcher'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15', '< 4.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'foreman'
# end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

#Add Sprockets for installing gems
gem 'sprockets-rails', '>= 2.3.2', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'

#Add Bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap', '>= 4.1.3'

#Add JQuery (for Bootstrap)
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3.1'

#Add Chart.js for analytics
gem 'chart-js-rails', '~> 0.1.6' 

#Add Devise for Authorization and Authentication
gem 'devise', '~> 4.4.3'

#Add Font Awesome Icons
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.2.0'

#Mini-Magick for Image Processing (のし Generator)
gem 'mini_magick'

#Auto-upload setup for AWS S3
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'carrierwave-google-storage'

# Easy Categories for Manual Articles
gem 'ancestry'

# CKEditor WYSIWYG text editor
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'ckeditor', github: 'galetahub/ckeditor'

# Sendgrid for confirmations, etc.
gem 'sendgrid-ruby'
```

And here's the error when I try to generate the scaffold:

```
rails generate scaffold Market namae:string address:string phone:string repphone:string fax:string cost:decimal excost:decimal history:string
      invoke  active_record
   identical    db/migrate/20181029224847_create_markets.rb
   identical    app/models/market.rb
      invoke    test_unit
   identical      test/models/market_test.rb
   identical      test/fixtures/markets.yml
      invoke  resource_route
       route    resources :markets
      invoke  scaffold_controller
   identical    app/controllers/markets_controller.rb
      invoke    erb
       exist      app/views/markets
    conflict      app/views/markets/index.html.erb
    Overwrite /home/mudl/kanri/Dropbox/funabiki-online-h/app/views/markets/index.html.erb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] n
        skip      app/views/markets/index.html.erb
   identical      app/views/markets/edit.html.erb
   identical      app/views/markets/show.html.erb
    conflict      app/views/markets/new.html.erb
    Overwrite /home/mudl/kanri/Dropbox/funabiki-online-h/app/views/markets/new.html.erb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] n
        skip      app/views/markets/new.html.erb
Traceback (most recent call last):
    71: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    70: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
    69: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
    68: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
    67: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    66: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    65: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    64: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    63: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    62: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    61: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    60: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    59: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
    58: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    57: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    56: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/generate/generate_command.rb:26:in `perform'
    55: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/generators.rb:276:in `invoke'
    54: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
    53: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
    52: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
    51: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
    50: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
    49: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
    48: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    47: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    46: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/group.rb:133:in `_invoke_from_option_scaffold_controller'
    45: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/group.rb:266:in `_invoke_for_class_method'
    44: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/shell.rb:68:in `with_padding'
    43: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/group.rb:277:in `block in _invoke_for_class_method'
    42: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:115:in `invoke'
    41: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
    40: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
    39: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
    38: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
    37: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
    36: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    35: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    34: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/group.rb:133:in `_invoke_from_option_template_engine'
    33: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/group.rb:266:in `_invoke_for_class_method'
    32: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/shell.rb:68:in `with_padding'
    31: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/group.rb:274:in `block in _invoke_for_class_method'
    30: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/group.rb:274:in `instance_exec'
    29: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/generators/rails/scaffold_controller/scaffold_controller_generator.rb:26:in `block in <class:ScaffoldControllerGenerator>'
    28: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:115:in `invoke'
    27: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
    26: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
    25: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
    24: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
    23: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
    22: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    21: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    20: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb:18:in `copy_view_files'
    19: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb:18:in `each'
    18: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb:19:in `block in copy_view_files'
    17: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb:19:in `each'
    16: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in copy_view_files'
    15: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/generators/named_base.rb:24:in `template'
    14: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/generators/named_base.rb:49:in `inside_template'
    13: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/generators/named_base.rb:25:in `block in template'
    12: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb:115:in `template'
    11: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:25:in `create_file'
    10: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/actions.rb:95:in `action'
     9: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:60:in `invoke!'
     8: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:113:in `invoke_with_conflict_check'
     7: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:72:in `on_conflict_behavior'
     6: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:46:in `identical?'
     5: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:53:in `render'
     4: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb:116:in `block in template'
     3: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:876:in `result'
     2: from /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:876:in `eval'
     1: from (erb):2:in `template'
(erb):2:in `concat': can't modify frozen String (FrozenError)
```

As you can see it seems to be having an issue when it gets to the "_form.html" part of the scaffold generation.

I checked to make sure there were no strange permissions on files. I suspect it has something to do with Foreman (which is a Heroku thing), or maybe dotenv (which is necessary for local development stuff, so I can store secrets). I found some posts elsewhere about previous beta versions of rails 5.1 have issues with Thor, but I don't even know what Thor does (it is some dependency) and they said that that bug was fixed on subsequent releases (e.g. I'm using 5.2 anyway).

My other theory is that it's related to Jbuilder and json stuff, which I'm also new to, and don't even know where to begin to tackle.

Any ideas? In the meantime I'm going to work without scaffolding.

Anyway, thank you for your time!

Thank you for your time!

---

Update!

Well, I solved the problem on my own, and just wanted to report back. So, I forgot I had had trouble installing Nokogiri as well. Whenever I ran "bundle update" I was getting an error that said I needed to make sure the latest version of Nokogiri was installed correctly before continuing. I ignored this, because I couldn't figure out out. This was solved by simply following the instructions at [nokogiri.org](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html) and installing the necessary libraries:

> sudo apt-get install build-essential patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev
> liblzma-dev
>
> gem install nokogiri

After I did this I thought to myself "Uh, duh, this is probably the solution to the scaffolding issue." Indeed it was.

Comment: What are you using foreman for?, can you remove it, run bundle and try again the command that gave you that error?

Comment: Occasionally I was running "rails server" instead of "heroku local" in my development environment. I ran into some errors, and I think foreman was leftover from me trying things to solve that.

Anyway, I removed it and have no problems running the server either way now--so thank you for that.

I ran "gem uninstall foreman" (there were multiple versions I pressed 3 to remove all). I also removed it from my gemfile. Then I ran "gem cleanup", just to cleanup anything leftover. Then I ran "bundle install", and the "rails g scaffold.." from above.

Unfortunately I get the exact same error.

Comment: Another update. Also recently disabled turbolinks, it was messing with bootstrap so popovers weren't working. Disabling this also did not fix the scaffolding problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Details above, but:

> Well, I solved the problem on my own, and just wanted to report back.
>   So, I forgot I had had trouble installing Nokogiri as well. Whenever I
>   ran "bundle update" I was getting an error that said I needed to make
>   sure the latest version of Nokogiri was installed correctly before
>   continuing. I ignored this, because I couldn't figure out out. This
>   was solved by simply following the instructions at nokogiri.org and
>   installing the necessary libraries:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install build-essential patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev
>
> gem install nokogiri
> ```
>
> After I did this I thought to myself "Uh, duh, this is probably the
>   solution to the scaffolding issue." Indeed it was.